# SyntaxError: The requested module 'xxx' does not provide an export named 'xxx'

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, es6-modules

I have created a local package which is built with rollup and produce a file `dist/index.d.ts` with type declaration :

```
declare function foo(bar: string): string;
export { foo };
```

My module `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  /* ... */
}
```

I list this package as depedency of a rest API, with a `package.json` looking like this

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "build": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc",
    "test": "jest",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mypackage": "^1.0.0",
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

And a `tsconfig.json` being

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

When I try to build i got the error

```
import { foo } from "mypackage";
         ^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'mypackage' does not provide an export named 'foo'
```

Whereas I have also a React app with same `tsconfig.json` file (except for ts-node section), where all works perfectly.

I am pretty lost on where to search, I found a lot of similar issue but nothing really worked.

Thanks for your help

EDIT :

Testing I found that if I remove `/dist/cjs` folder in mypackage I now got an error building the API :

```
throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND
```

While my React package still build (so using `/dist/esm`).
I am pretty sure the isue is here but I don't understand why API build using commonJS and not esm whith package configuration and tsconfig I choose ...

I also tried to add a function

```
export forTest() {
  return foo("hello");
}
```

To test it with jest :

```
it('should use foo function', () => {
  expect(forTest()).toBe('bar');
});
```

And it works well, so I think mypackage is good, there is juste a misconfiguration in my API build, but what ?

Comment: You need `export function foo(bar: string): string;`, not `declare`

Comment: Actually it is export, i didn't add the file totally and there is a `export { foo };` at the end.
As I say this work on an other package, I don't understand the diff